# disabling a date range in angular 4 calender

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular 4. I'm using angular 4 calendar and I want to disable the dates until current date.

I have read the previous answer but it doesn't work for me.Is there a simple way to disable the dates in the calendar.

here is my html code

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <div class="form-group FormComponents">
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fromDate" style="width: 170px;" name="FromDate" [ngModel]="FromDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'"
          (ngModelChange)="FromDate  = $event" (change)="FromDateChanged()">
      </div>
    </div>
```

here is my component.ts code

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from "../../environments/environment";
import { PersonPermitsMasterDetailsSrevices } from "./person-permits-master-details-services";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { UpperCaseTextDirective } from '../../uppercase.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-person-permits-master-details',
  templateUrl: './person-permits-master-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./person-permits-master-details.component.css']
})
export class PersonPermitsMasterDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use min or max attributes for date inputs.

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
Enter a date before 1980-01-01:<br>
<input type="date" name="bday" max="1979-12-31"><br><br>
Enter a date after 2018-02-23:<br>
<input type="date" name="bday" min="2018-02-23"><br><br>
<input type="submit"> 
</form>
```

Comment: this is working but how can I remove the hard coded date and get the min date from component.ts dynamically?

Comment: Use another variable & use ngmodel